# How did it all happen?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

Everything that believers are saying about WHY they pray is real as it is natural to humans to be afraid of unknown and grab that last straw if they do not see another solution to a problem...especially if it is about life or health or love for our dearest. All the history, literature and my experience confirm this is true. However, once we start to rationalize any rituals in any religion (prayers etc.), things go sidewise. As a matter of fact, I believe that individuals as well as groups and communities stop caring and working hard on anything once they start to believe in the contract with HIM and promise that everything will be all right as long as they follow certain rules. The difference in rules (how to pray, who and what to believe in, shape and form...) are sufficient to start wars, hatred and fights in the whole world. It is no coincidence that those rituals are not as widespread and practiced in richer and safer societies, countries and parts of the world. It almost looks as if the religiousness is the one that keeps individuals and societies back.
And...I swear...in no way I am trying to offend anyone as I personally come from a deeply religious country and this explanation seems to best fit into the factual world I come from.

Comment: And yet, many religious communities are well known for superior work ethic, see e.g. [Protestant work ethic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestant_work_ethic). You should avoid one-dimensional reasoning and sweeping generalizations of this sort. And asking for feedback on users' personal ponderings is off-topic on this site.

Comment: The topic of the question can't s at all be understood from the title. Reformulation it would allow your question better visibility, and better answers.

Comment: Religions are based on beliefs. Every religion tends to impose its own belief or world view - from antiquity to the present, and the most dominant beliefs are as a result of power (to persuade, insist and control) and necessity (faith, survival). From ancient Egypt to the present, we find the same myths and ideas and narratives played out repeatedly, especially in respect of the concept of kings and gods and afterlife (to ensure survival). Society is developing in a such away that we are able to understand more about the fundamental nature of existence, and so there are less unknowns, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the question -- although it might be good to narrow in a little bit further on what you'd like someone here to explain to you...? You're touching on a problem which is the crux of anthropogenesis in a way -- how do we adapt to rule-following behavior without being destroyed by it in turn?

1. I wanted to react quickly to your point about irrational or superstitious rituals, which as you say can mark a region as "backwards" -- yet nevertheless these rituals are *made* effective according to the social logic of ceremonial ritual and formal prohibition. Girard for instance -- when discussing the 'evil eye' phenomena -- remarks that of course there is also lynching associated with these sorts of things, citing examples in places like the southern US. There is a whole sociological drama unfolding wherein the rationality of particular acts is irrelevant, which raises another problem...
2. The public use of reason is a paradox, because if it were to be used 'effectively', then everything collapses; everything that humans have made is hodgepodge end-to-end, because the universe is chaos. We can reason about pieces of the world, convince ourselves regions of it make 'sense' but in the long run if you really believe in questioning certainties it does cast doubt on the veridicality of human reason itself (see Descartes for more on this problem.)

Comment: Why do I have a feeling that REASON is an unpopular word... as if it is threatening to human kind? Reasoning in my opinion is predicting what is going to happen next based on prior, as educated as possible, observations. If, for instance, average temperature dries our wells and lands and rises from year to year, it would be more reasonable to migrate "north" rather than stay and pray for your children's wellbeing. Thereby I appeal that reasoning of an experienced and educated adult is far more advanced and reliable than of a child.